# Recognize automatically extensions in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have a several Ms Office 97 documents with extension doc and xls however with the new extensions DOCX and XLSX.

**Is there any possibilities that the SharePoint Document Library will recognize them and overwrite them automatically ?**

Thanks.

Comment: If I get you correctly you need to replace the file `file.doc` with `file.docx`. I had answered on similar lines. You can find my answer [**here**](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/140238/20540). When we upload a document to SharePoint (if we enable the overwrite option) it identifies the file to overwrite by its name. If we need to replace file then we first would have to rename it. I couldn't find any API which renames the file in a document library. However you can trick SharePoint by moving the file to the same document library and renaming it (including the file extension).